# Convert ShortTime string to DateTime format

Tags: c#, datetime

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;

string newTime = time.ToShortTime();
```

How to convert this newTime string into DateTime format

Comment: which datetime format?

Comment: Before asking a question please at-least first google it..

Comment: If you have only string with time and you want to display it in different format, then you need to parse string back to DateTime object (but you'll loose information about date) or `TimeSpan` and use `ToString` with required format string, e.g. `ToString("HH-mm")`

Comment: There is no `ToShortTime()` method for `DateTime` class. Is this a custom method that you define? Could be it [`ToShortTimeString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshorttimestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

Comment: Finaly I found an answer 

    const string FMT = "O";
    DateTime now1 = DateTime.Now;
    string strDate = now1.ToString(FMT);
    DateTime now2 = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, FMT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: @Moumit Mondal - I try goodle several times but didn't get perfect answer. You don't need me to inform that...

Comment: @Tharinda_tpw - In that case please make your question more `clear` to viewer so that it's shows any `research effort` .. Your question seems like `beginner` learner question ... Now, do not use any unconstructive, offensive or rude words or voices in future it might  make your account `inactive`... So be pleased ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;

string newTime = time.ToShortTimeString();

DateTime dt = new DateTime();
DateTime.TryParse(newTime,out dt);
```

Note : It will set current Date.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I found an answer

```
const string FMT = "O";
DateTime now1 = DateTime.Now;
string strDate = now1.ToString(FMT);
DateTime now2 = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, FMT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```